# Passing each pdf from a directory to a function and get output as new txt file for each pdf's

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, typeerror, pdfminer, pdftotext

I have written a function that converts each pdf from a directory into text and I want to get the converted text from the pdf's as txt files. I am getting

```
"TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple".
```

Can anyone please help me with this. Attaching code here:

```
import io
import os
import os.path
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
    fake_file_handle = io.BytesIO()
    converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
    page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)

    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, 
                                      caching=True,
                                      check_extractable=True):
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)

        text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()

    # close open handles
    converter.close()
    fake_file_handle.close()

    if text:
        return text

def parse_pdf(filename):
    "Parse a pdf into text"
    content = io.getPDFContent(filename)
    encoded = content.encode("utf-8")
    ## split of the pdf extension to add .txt instead.
    (root, _) = os.path.splitext(filename)
    text_file = open(root + ".txt", "w")
    text_file.write(encoded)
    text_file.close()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdf_path = 'C:\\trainingdata_eng'    
    for file in os.walk(pdf_path):
        extract_text_from_pdf(file)

    for f in file:
        parse_pdf(f)
```

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: Yes it's solved